# How come the links in my footer section remain purple and underlined even when I use CSS to change that

Tags: css

I've spent hours on this, but even though I was able to manipulate the links the first time I used them in my code it would seem that the links on my footer won't change no matter what I do...

any advice/hint/solution would be appreciated...

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML     4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>usaelectricalsystemshome</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection">
body{
    background: black;
}
#wrap {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: blue;
}
#alldivs{
}
#header{ 
    background: blue;
}
#nav{
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background:blue repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #42432d;
    border-width:1px 0;
}
#nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav a:link,
#nav a:visited {
    color:#000;
    background:#FFFFF0;
    float:center;
    width:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #42432d;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 1em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover,
#nav a:focus {
    color:#fff;
    background:blue;
}
#main{
    background: white;
    float: left;
    width: 800px
}
#sidebar{
    background: gray;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
#footer{
    background: blue;
    clear: both;
}
#footernav a:link{
    color:gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footernav li{
    display: inline;
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}

</style> 
</head>



<body>
<br>
<div id="alldivs">
<div id ="wrap">
<div id="header"><p>This is the header, put something here!!</br>safsdf</p></div>
<ul id="nav">
<li id="home"><a href="link">HOME</a></li>
<li id="services"><a href="link">SERVICES</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="link">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main"><p>
MAIN CONTENT
</p></div>
<div id="sidebar">sidebar space</div>
<div id="footer">
<p>
this is the footer
</p>
<ul id="footernav">
<li id="footerhome"><a href="link">HOME</a></li>
<li id="footerservices"><a href="link">SERVICES</a></li>
<li id="footercontact"><a href="link">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: a:link is nothing.. just use a { color: gray; } instead.

Comment: The correct answer is that javi needs to style the :visited pseudo-selector. a:link is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is off:

```
a { color:gray } /* <a href="#">Foo</a> */
```

This will change the link color (affects visited links as well):

```
a:hover { color:green } /* <a href="#">Foo</a> */
```

This will change it when hovered.

Comment: I think you might be a bit mistaken here Jonathan. a:link is valid. There are 4 primary states for an anchor, link, visited, active and hover.

Comment: @Jamie +1 You're right; it's just been years since I've written `a:link`, and the fact that his `href` had a value of `link` made me think there was some confusion on his part - I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I just wrote link in to show that a link would go in that section

Comment: I treid this and it doesn't work. It seems logical to me but it won't change it's still purple.

Comment: I wrote #footernav a:{ color:gray} and I also tried #footernav a:link{color:gray} neither works...

Comment: @javi Don't put `:` in there. Just `a { color:gray }`.

Comment: @javi We've all been there - 10 years from now you'll look back on these days and smile :)

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
#footernav a:link, #footernav a:visited {
```

Remember, links are *either* `:link`, or `:visited`, never both.

Answer (score 0):

try `#footernav li a:link` not `#footernav a:link` Your traverse through the DOM seems off.

Comment: Your extra specificity seems unnecessary Tim. The selector #footernav a:link should be fine in this contex.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a:visited { color:#000;} between the style tag.